DevTools - how to find click handler?
Here's how my page looks in the DevTools (Chrome/Firefox/Edge/whatever else):

The selected button handles clicking on it, but I don't see the corresponding handler in the DevTools. How can I find this handler in the DevTools? I have tons of JS and see no obvious way to locate suitable click handler there; hope DevTools would help me with this task. If DevTools can't help with it, I'd like to know an alternative that could help me.

Firefox displays the handlers when you click the event label after the tag in the DOM tree.
